Is an elementary substructure of a countable abelian group a direct summand?
The question:
If we take an uncountable undecomposable abelian group, then a countable elementary substructure is not a direct summand.
What if we restrict ourselves to countable groups? Is every elementary substructure a direct summand then?
Further context:
An elementary substructure $A$ of an abelian group $B$ is a pure subgroup. Meaning, for every $n\in\mathbb N$, $nA=nB\cap A$. In fact, we can show that elementary substructures are precisely pure subgroups which are elementary equivalent.
Every direct summand of an abelian group is a pure subgroup. But the converse is not true. However none of the examples I found are elementary substructures. Such examples exist, because there are uncountable undecomposable abelian groups (although I don't know of an example), so it's natural to ask if there's a countable counter example.

I believe I found a counter example. Take $G=\bigoplus_{q\in\mathbb Q}\mathbb Z$ and its subgroup $N$ the kernel of the canonical surjective map to $\mathbb Q$. Then $N$ is a pure subgroup because $\mathbb Q$ is torsion-free. It's also a free group because it's a subgroup of a free abelian group. $N$ is clearly not finitely generated therefore it's an isomorphic pure subgroup of $G$, which means it's an elementary substructure. But $N$ isn't a direct summand because that would imply $\mathbb Q$ is projective.
